# img src is inexistent and another image is displayed instead

Tags: html, image

I know this wil sound crazy, but it is really happening:

I have the following code in my page (this was extracted directed from the browser, i.e. it is the generated code):

```
<img height="100" width="100" src="../image/itens/0/135.jpg" onerror="this.src='../image/icons/noImageAvailable300.png'" id="135">
```

The thing is: there is an image that appears (as expected) but the the file `"../image/itens/0/135.jpg"` doesn't actually exist!!!

The image that appears is the image `"../image/itens/0/134.jpg"`. When I left click on the shown image and the click on "open image in new tab" the image that is shown is actually `"../image/itens/0/134.jpg"`.

How the hell is this even possible?
Any insights?

Comment: Is there any way I can see it live?

Comment: Did you create the code? Also, is it on a machine where you can test them out?

Comment: Did you try cleaning out your browser's cache?

Comment: Maybe the `src` is changed using Javascript. This isn't visible when viewing the document source, because the Javascript isn't executed then.

Comment: @NikolaR. Sorry, it's online but on an admin page.

Comment: @SrdjanGrubor yes, I did. Not that

Comment: @GolezTrol It must be that then! I'll check!

Comment: Make a separate .html file & post its LINK here if you want help from us.

Comment: I found the origin of the problem. The server redirects the original file path to another address (e.g. if I type  www.mysite.com/images/135.jpg I am redirected to www.mysite.com/images/134.jpg ). No JS, nothing. Just by accessing the image. Any idea why that is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem's origin was that my server would redirect the unexisting file path to a file path that existed.
The reason it did that is because it had the spelling check activated by default. 
The solution for that problem is changing this parameter on the .htaccess file, by adding the following line to it:

```
CheckSpelling off
```